# Informatica Date/Time Conversion

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

in one of the requirment informatica fetching data from flat file as source file and insert records into a temporary table temp of DB2 database. Flat file has one column as datetime datatype (YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS). However, informatica fetching this column as string datatype (Since Informatica date format is different from this column & DB2). So before loading into temp table of DB2 database, I need to convert back this column into Datetime format.

With Expresion transformation, I can do this but I dont know how? `To_date` conversion function (`TO_DATE(FIELD, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS')`) is there but it will take care of date only (YYYY/MM/DD). Its not taking care of time (HH:MM:SS) and because of this records are not inserting into temp table.

How can I convert datetime from String datatype to DB2 datetime format (YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried to use the **month** format string (i.e. `MM`) for the **minutes** part of the date.

You need to use `MI`:

```
TO_DATE(FIELD, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
```